# Continuously copying a string to the clipboard, doesn't work

Tags: c#, console-application, clipboard

I want to make a C# Console Application which continuously saves a string to the clipboard. I've tried the following code [further down] and when I tried it the first time it actually saved the string to the clipboard, but after I copied something else I didn't overwrite that. I think it's an easy fix and I'm just overlooking something.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Crackster
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = -10;

            while (i < 0)
            {
                
                Clipboard.SetText("kolleeeg");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Console.Write("Success\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use while loop instead of  `goto`. What do you mean by `it never worked again` ?

Comment: How do you find that it didn't work? With your code it's pure coincidence whether the clipboard contains nothing or the text when you copy it somewhere.

Comment: When I tried to run the code later on, I was not able to paste anything from the clipboard. The clipboard just stayed empty.

Comment: Which is not surprising, given the fact that you empty it in a fast loop. You should only clear and update it when it contains something else than what you want it to be.

Comment: Probably because you clear it by the speed of your CPU... Try putting a delay in there to see if it works....
Also  ``ClipBoard.SetText(...)`` already clears the clipboard.

Comment: how about trying without a loop in the first place?

Comment: Sounds like a bad approach to begin with, you are hammering the clipboard. Try monitoring for clipboard changes using [`SetClipBoardViewer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboardviewer) or using a [`Clipboard Format Listener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboardviewer).

Comment: @DaMachk Thanks a lot. I changed my code according to your suggestions. Unfortunately I doesn't change the fact that after copying something else, it doesn't work anymore. I mean the console still returns success, but the clipboard doesn't change to "kolleeeg".